# centos 7 chromium extensions install give ERROR_RE_ENCODING_THEME_IMAGE

Tags: centos, chrome

When I try to install extensions in chromium under CentOS 7 in the default user account I get : `Could not install package: 'ERROR_RE_ENCODING_THEME_IMAGE'`.

However, in an account created by myself there is no problem.

Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bug on chromium package [Bug 1493664](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1493664).

Install the [`chromium-61.0.3163.100-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-testing-x86_64/chromium-61.0.3163.100-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) from testing.